# Google cloud load balancing and reverse DNS

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, reverse-dns, ptr-record

I have a domain example.com pointing at a Google Cloud load balancer. Requests get served by one of several Compute Engines behind the load balancer.

The load balancer ip is 1.2.3.4

Now when I send email from email@example.com sometimes it gets black listed because the reverse lookup for 1.2.3.4 does not return example.com instead it returns 71.22.211.130.bc.googleusercontent.com

I know that I can set a PTR on the individual virtual machines behind the load balancer but I don't think this will solve the problem.

Is there a solution that will make 1.2.3.4 return example.com or another typical solution?

Comment: Could you explain in detail how you are sending your email? From where, using which services? SPF? Using actual domains, IP addresses and examples of errors helps to narrow it down.

Comment: We are using Rolby to send emails using @legalcentric.com

Comment: Ip address of legalcentric.com is 130.211.22.71
Office 365 is used for managing email accounts. 
MX legalcentric-com.mail.protection.outlook.com
SPF v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all

The Rolby emails are blacklisted on https://www.spamhaus.org/pbl/

Answer (score 0):

[I would leave a comment, but I don't have enough reputation]

Have you try checking this [website](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/checkmx/check?domain=legalcentric.com&dkim_selector=)? There you can see as Google says "SPF must allow Google servers to send mail on behalf of domain", and it links to this [article](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786). I also gives some other recommendation, it may helps you.